# How to scale Redis?

Tags: redis

I have a single instance Redis deployment, and my application uses multiple databases within that deployment.

I would like to scale it up, however, the issue is, RedisCluster does not support multiple databases. What are my best options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've only two options:

1. You refactor your application layer to use [sharding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)) (i.e. *Redis Cluster*).
2. You use regular master-slave replication to load balance your Redis work load.

Comment: I have gone with n. 1.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, IIUC, you have another option (besides the two that @Matias put) - stop using shared databases and, instead, spin up a dedicated Redis server process for each database.

If your server has more than 2 CPU cores, this will allow you to utilize them better. In your application(s) code, replace calls to `SELECT` with a connection to the relevant Redis server.

Comment: Given that we have 2 stacks (one for failover), this would mean 4 redis clusters, so 12 servers. I have chosen to go with single db for now.